# Objects between objects python

Tags: python, list

I want to make from the list:

```
L=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

This:

```
L=[1,1,1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,6,1,7,1,8,1,9]
```

This is, put the 1 between the objects in list. Can someone help me?

Comment: Isn't there a 1 too many, at the start? That is to say; you prepended a 1 and put 1s between the original values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the result in your example (1 before each object):

```
L = [y for x in L for y in (1, x)]
```

For the result described by your text (1 between the objects):

```
L = [y for x in L for y in (x, 1)]
L.pop()
```

If you hate multiple `for` clauses in comprehensions:

```
L = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable((1, x) for x in L))
```

Comment: @DavidUnric: well, I wouldn't promise that it wins a performance shootout, but it might well be THE first version :-)

Comment: It's very nice usage of nested list-comps.  If I didn't really dislike nested list comprehensions, I would really like this answer.  +1 :)

Comment: @mgilson: would it help at all to write it across several lines, so each `for` clause is on its own line? Most comprehensions with multiple `for` clauses that I use are still *way* simpler than the average SQL statement with an equal number of joins. They can be easier or harder to read according to how they're presented :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop -- maybe.  For some reason, these have always just been mind-benders for me.  The itertools solution is nice too.  Both ways, it's a great answer.  And yeah, definitely simpler than an average SQL statement.  A lot simpler than the average regex too ... But I hope our bar for readability is a lot higher than the average readability in those two languages ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
print ([i for t in zip([1] * len(L), L) for i in t])
```

**Output**

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 1, 7, 1, 8, 1, 9]
```

Comment: Yes, I discovered this too; see my comment on the question

Answer (score 2):

I've always really loved slice assignment:

```
>>> L = range(1, 10)
>>> L
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

>>> # Done with setup, let the fun commence!
>>> LL = [None] * (len(L)*2)  # Make space for the output
>>> LL[1::2] = L
>>> LL[::2] = [1] * len(L)

>>> LL  # Lets check the results, shall we?
[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 1, 7, 1, 8, 1, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple for loop would suffice

```
for item in list:
  newList.append(1)
  newList.append(item)
list = newList
```

Comment: Just `newList.pop()` removes the last element. Swap the `appends()` and lose the `.pop()` however, to match the OP sample output.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, I was reading the sample output opposite it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Using [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html):

```
>>> L=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> from itertools import chain, izip, repeat
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(izip(repeat(1), L)))
[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 1, 7, 1, 8, 1, 9]
```